# JSON received as quote (with "" mark)

Tags: php, json

I keep receiving my JSON from my web service inside quotation marks, like this:

```
"[{"id":"1","nombre":"Cecilia","correo":"csoto@ts.edu.mx","telefono":"5529964"},{"id":"2","nombre":"Romero","correo":"","telefono":"5435432"},{"id":"3","nombre":"nick","correo":"carlos@mail.com","telefono":"12345"}]"
```

Notice the "" before the brackets and I don't know why.
I'm using jacwright's restServer (https://github.com/jacwright/RestServer) with this function:

```
public function getUsers()
{
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "estudiantes";

    // Create connection
    $array = array();

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT id, nombre, correo, telefono FROM estudiante";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            $res = array("id" => $row["id"], "nombre" => $row["nombre"], "telefono" => $row["telefono"], "correo" => $row["correo"]);
            array_push($array, $res);
            //echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["nombre"]. " " . $row["correo"]. "<br>";
        }
    }

    $conn->close();

    return json_encode($array)  ;
}
```

Can somebody insight me why it keeps adding these quotation marks?

Comment: Because JSON is a string so you need to parse it.

Comment: `JSON.parse()`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: Exactly what @aldrin27 said above ^. It's a string, so if you're using jquery, just parse it - [`jQuery.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ar/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: Try a simple `json_encode([])` and see if that produces a similar result.

Comment: parsing it in my php file? Or on my client? I parse it on my client and I tought it was a problem on my client application, but I asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33856445/gson-php-call-gives-illegalstateexception and the user told me it was the php, not the client code.

Comment: I'm using `json_encode($array)` but it still shows my JSON ouput as a String (with the quotations).

Comment: Hit run and check this: http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/fymw-3isv, echo you json_encoded $array

Comment: Thanks for anwsering. The echo runs without the quotation marks, but `return json_encode($array)` returns a string. I need to use return instead of echo, how can I use `return` and not get a string?

Comment: I usually pass JSON result using echo, it feels easier to work with for me because after using `JSON.parse()` or `$.parseJSON()` the result is an array, not only me, if you search on here or google you will see people mostly use `echo` instead of return to retrieve data using ajax

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick example simulating your case, using echo to return JSON encoded array:

**JS:**

```
$.get('json.php', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  if (data) {
    //Check the console, everything is working like charm
    newData = $.parseJSON(data);
    console.log(data);
    console.log('--------------' + 'Elements count:' + newData.length);
    console.log('--------------' + newData);
  }
});
```

**json.php:**

```
<?php
    $myArr = array(
        array("id"=>"1","nombre"=>"Cecilia","correo"=>"csoto@ts.edu.mx","telefono"=>"5529964"),
        array("id"=>"2","nombre"=>"Romero","correo"=>"","telefono"=>"5435432"),
        array("id"=>"3","nombre"=>"nick","correo"=>"carlos@mail.com","telefono"=>"12345")
    );
    $jsonData = json_encode($myArr);
    echo $jsonData;
?>
```

---

Same above code using `return $jsonData;` instead of `echo $jsonData;` in *json.php* it gives me the following in the console:

- emptiness for `data`
- console error:

> ReferenceError: newData is not defined

Comment: Thank you, I'm no expert in javaScript and I don't know why there is ReferenceError, I think my problem is under my implementation of the github project I copied above, as far as I could understand I needed to return my JSON so the restServer could use it and display it. Using echo doesn't work inside my custom method, as it is not displayed on the request.

Comment: the error happened because data is empty when i use `return` in php, so javascript complained, and I'm sorry i don't know about REST stuff but usually people use `echo`, best wishes and hopefully you'll find an answer soon

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'll keep looking.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of getting the quotes in the returned string is because the server (https://github.com/jacwright/RestServer) is doing json_encode itself. So when you return the data from your function `getUsers` and you have used `json_encode` it is converted to a json string and when RestServer returns it to you it sees it only as a string therefore adding quotes around it.

If you look at the `TestController` you will see that it returns an object `$user` not `json_encode($user)` and RestServer in it's `sendData` function actually uses the `json_encode` function.

So your code needs to be:

```
public function getUsers()
{
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "estudiantes";

    // Create connection
    $array = array();

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT id, nombre, correo, telefono FROM estudiante";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            $res = array("id" => $row["id"], "nombre" => $row["nombre"], "telefono" => $row["telefono"], "correo" => $row["correo"]);
            array_push($array, $res);
            //echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["nombre"]. " " . $row["correo"]. "<br>";
        }
    }

    $conn->close();

    return $array;
}
```

Also check out the function `sendData` in https://github.com/jacwright/RestServer/blob/master/source/Jacwright/RestServer/RestServer.php#L414 on line 414.

Comment: This was my original approach, to use `return $array`, but when I call this service on my client app, it reads it as a String rather than as an Object

Comment: You should use it with JSON.parse() in your client application. So `var object = JSON.parse(returnedDataFromServer)`

Comment: Obviously bluntly guessing you are using JavaScript. :P

Comment: I wish I was using JavaScript, I'm developing an android application, and reading the `InputStreamReader` with a `JsonReader` and no luck :( But thanks for commenting

Comment: Then that is a problem with the JAVA part of the application and not the php response. The php part should be fixed by my answer.

That being said I would point you to this: `JSONObject  jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(strJson);`
Read it as `JsonObject` and also look at this: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm and this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14742902/parse-json-data-using-jsonreader-or-jsonobject-jsonarray

And also advise to open a new question for the Android problem just so we keep issues separate.

Comment: Also ping the new question here so I can check it out and help. :)